# JPA criteria query count

Tags: jpa, count, persistence, criteria, builder

I've a problem with counting entities with CriteriaBuilder. First of, i've two entities - Category and Item. Category is tree of objects which can have one parent, many subcategories and items.
This is my actual data in mysql:

```
Category 0
  Category 0 0
    10 items
  Category 0 1
    10 items
  Category 0 2
    10 items
  Category 0 3
    10 items
Category 1
  Category 1 0
    10 items
  Category 1 1
    10 items
  Category 1 2
    10 items
  Category 1 3
    10 items
```

Category Entity:

```
@ManyToOne
private Category category;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Category> subcategories = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<ItemForSale> items = new ArrayList<>();

public List<Category> getAllCategories() {
    List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>();
    categories.add(this);
    getSubcategories().forEach((c) -> {
        categories.addAll(c.getAllCategories());
    });
    return categories;
}
```

My counting query which SHOULD count items depending of the criteria

```
public int getItemsForSaleCount(Category category) {
    CriteriaBuilder cm = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Long> cq = cm.createQuery(Long.class);
    Root<ItemForSale> root = cq.from(ItemForSale.class);
    cq.select(cm.count(cq.from(ItemForSale.class)));
    List<Category> categories = category.getAllCategories();
    if(categories.size() > 1) {
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        categories.forEach((c) -> {
            predicates.add(cm.equal(root.get("category"), c));
        });
        cq.where(cm.or(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()])));
    } else {
        cq.where(cm.equal(root.get("category"), category));
    }
    Query query = em.createQuery(cq);
    return Math.toIntExact((Long) query.getSingleResult());
}
```

Basically what is happening is that when i request Category 0 for example query result should be 40 but is 40 * 80 = 3200(correct result * total amount of items), same when i request subcategories, result is 10 * 80 = 800

EDIT:
I solved it, when i replace cq.from(ItemForSale.class)) with root it's working, could someone explain me the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/AbstractQuery.html#from(java.lang.Class)) for `AbstractQuery.from` answers your question:

> Create and add a query root corresponding to the given entity, **forming a cartesian product with any existing roots**.

Since you called `from` twice, and defined the `where` clause to involve only one of the roots, the query returns the 40 rows from the 'filtered' root cross-joined with the 80 results from the 'unfiltered' root.